# Create template-less user control. OnApplyTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I have "Service" custom control that doesn't need to be visual. I just add it to my view so it can bind to VM and perform some functionality.

Style looks like so:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:IdattInteractions">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:IdattInteractions">
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When view initialized I don't get `OnApplyTemplate` called on my control. Is that because `ControlTemplate` empty? How do I achieve functionality I need? I need to proble visual tree around this control for some functionality and I wanted to do it inside `OnApplyTemplate`.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if your "control" is not visual, then it should be a business logic object of some class, running in memory and interacting with the ViewModel if needed. No need to declare it in XAML.

Comment: It's a long discussion but I ended up with control for my specific situation since it is part of visual functionality. So, it affects visual but also binds to VM and listens to events to do what it needs to do.

Comment: It now seems to me that you have a VM for an entire View, but you need a logics back-end to make the control inside that view function properly. In this case you should have a control's view model interacting with a view's view model.

Comment: I'm trying to see if attached behavior will do the same. Seems like it might be cleaner solution

Comment: Go ahead, but there is a purely natural rule - in .net development, you can achieve the most in main language code, not in declarative XAML or some other technology part. I understand my opinion may be very subjective, but if the code gives you the most flexibility, you should try to stick with the code everywhere you need it. But I don't know your case to, so in your case attached behavior may indeed be better.

Comment: I sent you message via your website :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you "add it to your view" by declaring as a resource.  If that's the case, the reason you never receive a call to OnApplyTemplate is because your control is not part of the visual tree.  (Test it out: in the debugger, break at the end of your constructor.  You'll have a ResourceDictionary with your control living inside.  Try to keep following the Parent property until you reach your control.  You'll find the Parent will be null quite quickly within the hierarchy.)

To get a call from OnApplyTemplate, you'll need to add your custom control into the root layout container of some other control.  Then you'll be inside the visual tree.